# AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'error'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using python 2.7.10 and Phantom JS 1.9.8.

Recently, I started seeing issues on .close().

Specifically:

I set my browser object to `browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()

I then create the BeutifulSoup object:

```
browser.get(url)
webpage = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
```

on browser.close(), every now and then I get:

```
...
except socket.error as s_err:
AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'error'
```

Which gets triggered on 'catch clause':

```
except socket.error as s_err:
```

I can only assume that the cause for this 'catch' failure is that the socket has actually been closed despite the error and that something else in the close process has triggered the error.

Assuming I am correct, is there a way to actually capture the error?

I have a finally clause that ensures that the browser is terminated (so I do not get a complete crash):

```
finally:
   browser.quit()
```

Comment: Something has stomped on the name "socket". Fix it.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. If it was happening all the time, I could understand. It happens on average on 1/30,000 pages (open connection, load page, create soup, close connection, return soup). For now, I've added a generic clause:  except Exception as details:
                logger.info("Exception on browser.close(): " + str(details))

Comment: It happens only when an exception occurs. Because the name has been stomped on.

Comment: I get that. I am not clear what is 'stomping' it or why getting the page is fine and the exception occurs on close(). Nothing touches the object. See what the generic clause can provide.

Comment: Something else in the same scope is being bound to "socket".

Comment: This seems like a bug in the selenium webdriver impl for python. Have you tried another version or checked whether this bug is already reported?

Comment: Could not find anything on Google. I know phantomjs has various issues with close & quit. But until now it has been stable. So for now, I added a generic except clause to see what can be caught (if anything). As it happens on close, after I get the data, it is annoying but not a catastrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Issues found:

the exception clause `except (httplib.HTTPException, socket.error)` is wrong:

- it bundles two unrelated exceptions (not the end of the world but not ok)
- I actually `import errno` and `from socket import error as socket_error` but my exception clause uses a non-existent socket.error (theoretically it should work but...)

I have now split the exceptions and use errno test/check:

```
except socket_error as s_err:
     if s_err == errno.ECONNREFUSED or s_err == errno.ECONNRESET:
        ...
```